# SQL MACH() AGAINST() keyword length

Tags: mysql, sql, keyword, string-length, match-against

why does

```
SELECT * , MATCH(tags) AGAINST('php' IN BOOLEAN MODE) .. etc
```

doesn't returns anything (while php tags exists in many rows)

and

```
SELECT * , MATCH(tags) AGAINST('jquery' IN BOOLEAN MODE) .. etc
```

returns results ?

Is there a keyword searche char length min limit? is "php" keyword too short? :/

Is there anyway to make the query run searching trough "php" keyword?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are right, by default there is a 4 character limit for keywords.

It can be changed from the configuration file, option is called "ft_min_word_len".

Don't forget to restart MySQL service/daemon after changing the length.

Answer (score 1):

default minimum length is 4 so that is probably it